# MYSQL importing blank values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to import a CVS file that contains blank values but when I import them, they are replaced with zeros. (i.e. a cust_referred_by field that is blank is replaced with 0 in MySQL). I would like them to show blanks in my SQL.[image]

Comment: Is the column defined as `not null`?

Comment: What is data type of cust_referred_by? If its int(or any other numeric) it will have 0's as empty values.

Comment: the cust_referred_by is INT and yes it is nullable

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your field is nullable.

If it's not, then run something like this to fix it:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY cust_referred_by INT;
```

Also, depending on the way you do your import, you might be able to define how NULL values are provided.